# How to correct this error in creating Azure NSG with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-nsg

I am trying  to create a NSG in Azure with Terraform.

Terraform Version is **v0.15.2** with provider version **azurerm v2.61.0**

Here's the piece of code in my TF file.

```
  resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "SG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name


  security_rule = [{
    access                                     = "Allow"
    description                                = "SSH Rule"
    destination_address_prefix                 = "*"
    destination_address_prefixes               = ["*"]
    destination_port_range                     = "*"
    destination_port_ranges                    = ["22"]
    direction                                  = "Inbound"
    name                                       = "SSH Rule"
    priority                                   = 100
    protocol                                   = "Tcp"
    source_address_prefix                      = "*"
    source_address_prefixes                    = ["*"]
    source_port_range                          = "22"
    source_port_ranges                         = ["22"]
    source_application_security_group_ids      = [""]
    destination_application_security_group_ids = [""]

  }]
}
```

Now when I run `terraform plan` & `terraform apply`, I get the expected output as:

```
* only one of "source_port_range" and "source_port_ranges" can be used per security rule
* only one of "destination_port_range" and "destination_port_ranges" can be used per security rule
* only one of "source_address_prefix" and "source_address_prefixes" can be used per security rule
* only one of "destination_address_prefix" and "destination_address_prefixes" can be used per security rule
```

Now when I keep only `source_port_range, destination_port_range, source_address_prefix, destination_address_prefix` fields & run `terraform plan` again, it gives me following error:

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "security_rule": element 0: attributes "destination_address_prefixes",
│ "destination_port_ranges", "source_address_prefixes", and "source_port_ranges" are required.
```

If I add those & remove the earlier ones, I get:

```
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "security_rule": element 0: attributes "destination_address_prefix", "destination_port_range",  
│ "source_address_prefix", and "source_port_range" are required.
```

Why is this happening & how to get around with this issue?

**Update**

Took into consideration the point mentioned in the comment & made few changes to get it working.

Points to note:

- Even when it's mentioned Optional in the doc, Terraform needs all the keys in the security_rule block.
- Also, it doesn't allow Source/destination address_prefixes = ["*"] like this. Source/Destination address_prefix did the job.
- And where values are not mentioned, [] is expected instead of [""]

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "SG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name


  security_rule = [{
    access                                     = "Allow"
    description                                = "SSH Rule"
    destination_address_prefix                 = "*"
    destination_address_prefixes               = []
    destination_port_range                     = ""
    destination_port_ranges                    = ["22"]
    direction                                  = "Inbound"
    name                                       = "SSH Rule"
    priority                                   = 100
    protocol                                   = "Tcp"
    source_address_prefix                      = "*"
    source_address_prefixes                    = []
    source_port_range                          = "*"
    source_port_ranges                         = []
    source_application_security_group_ids      = []
    destination_application_security_group_ids = []

  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
  security_rule = [{
    access                                     = "Allow"
    description                                = "SSH Rule"
    destination_address_prefix                 = ""
    destination_address_prefixes               = ["*"]
    destination_port_range                     = ""
    destination_port_ranges                    = ["22"]
    direction                                  = "Inbound"
    name                                       = "SSH Rule"
    priority                                   = 100
    protocol                                   = "Tcp"
    source_address_prefix                      = ""
    source_address_prefixes                    = ["*"]
    source_port_range                          = ""
    source_port_ranges                         = ["22"]
    source_application_security_group_ids      = []
    destination_application_security_group_ids = []

  }]
}
```

You're defining values in both fields - i.e. Terraform will only accept one of either `destination_port_range` or `destination_port_ranges` and not both. Same goes for the other attributes.

Comment: Initially I did the changes suggested but it still returned errors. 
Apparently, even when it's mentioned Optional in the doc, Terraform needs all the keys in security_rule block.
Also, it doesn't allow Source/destination address_prefixes = ["*"] like this. 
Source/Destination address_prefix did the job. 
And where values are not mentioned, [] is expected instead of [""] .
But your main point of defining a single value is correct.

Comment: I actually missed the last two in my reply - I've fixed that. Yes actually it used to be optional - I still have code on terraform 13 that has only one of them defined. But it could now be required in v15. It's possible they didn't update the doc yet.